# Entity Framework with two (almost) identical models

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have two databases that are almost identical in schema but seperate in the data that is held within them.  The consuming application does not need to know about these differences so I am creating a service which will have the entity framework models but I want it to return a single type back.  For example:

```
**DatabaseA** -> EFModelA
- Customers
- Orders

**DatabaseB** -> EFModelB
- Customers
- Orders
```

I want to be able to return a `Customer` class through the a call rather than it returning either `EFModelA.Customer` or `EFModelB.Customer`.

I have have looked into two ways of doing this but can't work out which way will provide the least resistance in terms of maintenance.  They are:

1. Create a unified view of the data in DatabaseA which unions the data from DatabaseB so they application only sees one entity set.  The downside is working out how to make sure that they keys are unique but I can add an extra field to denote which database it came from.
2. Have 2 separate EF Models and have some way of scripting (e.g. T4 templates) a combined model of equivalent types and then implemented mapping code between the two EF types and the combined type.

Has anyone else come across this problem and how have you solved this?  If not, how would you tackle this problem?

Comment: How about using one DbContext and switch connection if needed?

Comment: The models are almost identical, there are a couple of fields in one database that do not exist in the other...I assume that this would cause a problem when executing the database queries.

Comment: have you tried starting with 1 context against both DBs? In non destructive mode of course ;-)  Bounded Contexts is a valid solution in some cases.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx